# SAX parsing problem in Android... empty elements?

Tags: java, xml, android, sax

I am using SAX to parse an XML file I'm pulling from the web. I've extended [DefaultHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) with code similar to:

```
public class ArrivalHandler extends DefaultHandler {    
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceUri, String localName, String qualifiedName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qualifiedName.equalsIgnoreCase("resultSet")) {
            System.out.println("got a resultset");
        } else if (qualifiedName.equalsIgnoreCase("location")) {
            System.out.println("got a location");
        } else if (qualifiedName.equalsIgnoreCase("arrival")) {
            System.out.println("got an arrival");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There was an unknown XML element encountered: '" + qualifiedName + "'");
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceUri, String localName, String qualifiedName) throws SAXException {
        // we'll just ignore this for now
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] chars, int startIndex, int length) throws SAXException {
        // ignore this too
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm just getting a series of empty elements. The log reads:

```
There was an unknown XML element encountered: ''
There was an unknown XML element encountered: ''
There was an unknown XML element encountered: ''
etc
```

This worked fine when I was just passing `parser.parse` a local file, but now I'm pulling it from the web with:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
resp = httpClient.execute("http://example.com/whatever");

SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
ArrivalHandler handler = new ArrivalHandler();
SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(resp.getEntity().getContent(), handler);
```

and I get the (apparently) empty results described above.

What I've looked into so far:

1. I converted the `InputStream` from `resp.getEntity().getContent()` to a string and dumped it out and it looks like I'm getting the XML from the server correctly.
2. There are no exceptions thrown but there is a warning that reads "`W/ExpatReader(232): DTD handlers aren't supported.`".

Any other ideas for what I'm doing incorrectly or how to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs for `ContentHandler.startElement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html):

> the qualified name is required when
>   the namespace-prefixes property is
>   true, and is optional when the
>   namespace-prefixes property is false
>   (the default).

So, do you have the namespace-prefixes property set to `true`?

Can you just cope with the uri and localName instead?

Comment: D'oh. `localName` gave my what I wanted. I don't understand why it's returning them differently in the different contexts though (reading from local vs remote).

Comment: Same thing happens to me when using Android. It's not related to "pulling it from the web".

In my junit tests of the library, it sets qualifiedName.

But when i use this library in an Android project, it sets localName instead of qualifiedName.

Don't know why :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Can you explain how to set name space prefix property to true.